# iTerm2, disable %/# sign after command

Tags: macos, iterm, iterm2

I've recently made the switch from OS X's Terminal app to iTerm2. There is a small issue which is annoying me. After every command a %-sign is printed out in the terminal.

I also have a Debian 6 VM, which I SSH to. On that machine I get a # instead of the %-sign.

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Why would you want to disable the prompt?  And are you saying you had no prompt visible in Terminal.app?  There should be no difference between the prompt in the two apps, since that is controlled in your shell's rc files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by setting *Report Terminal Type* to *rxvt* in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

that's the prompt, provided by whichever shell you're running. You can see which shell you're currently running with

```
echo $SHELL
```

then you can do some reading on the 'net about that particular shell and how to customize your environment. For example, if you're using bash, http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/ or http://www.macworld.com/article/146550/2010/02/rootprompt.html would be good places to start.